# How to use arc to deal with exim4+mailman?

Tags: exim, mailman

How to use arc to deal with exim4+mailman ? How to config with exim4 and mailman3?

mailman.cfg:

```
enabled: yes
dmarc:yes
dkim:yes
privkey: /etc/dkim/dkim.pem
authserv_id: *******
selector: s201512
domain: *******
sig_headers: From,Date,Subject,Message-ID,Content-Type,MIME-Version
dkim_enabled: yes
dmarc_enabled: yes
```

exim4:

```
remote_smtp:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp
  arc_sign = *******:s201512:/etc/exim4/dkim/dkim.pem
```